# Clarification of the statement of the Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, yoneda-lemma

Here is one version of the Yoneda lemma:
[Yoneda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIiNm.png)
(Previously, for any category $\mathcal C$ and any $X\in \text{Ob} \mathcal C$, the guy $h_X$ was defined as the functor $\operatorname {Hom}_{\mathcal C}(-,X):\mathcal C^{op}\to \mathcal{Set}$. And $\mathcal {PreSh(C)}=\mathcal {Set}^{\mathcal C^{op}}$)

[Here](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/catlog/notes/catlog0.pdf) is another verison (Lemma A.4.6, p.21). There, $\text y$ is a functor $$\text y: \mathcal C\to \mathcal {Set}^{\mathcal C^{op}}$$ (see p.20).

My questions are:

1. Are these two statements equivalent, and if so, why? In particular, I don't see why $h_A$ in the first statement is the same functor as $\text y$ in the second statement.
2. In the first statement, what is meant by "functorial in $F$ and $A$"?
3. In the second statement, why does the first assertion mean that $\text{Nat} (\text yA, F)\simeq FA$, and what is $\simeq$? (As far as I understand, the first assertion says that there are natural transformations between the two functors whose compositions are identities, but I don't see how the statement $\text{Nat} (\text yA,F)\simeq FA$ follows, nor do I understand what it means)

Comment: $y$ and $h_X$ aren't the same functor; $y(X)$ and $h_X$ are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. They're the same statement, but note that $h_X$ is a functor $C^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ and $y$ is a functor $C\to\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$; they're not stating they're the same functor. In this case, $h_X$ is the same presheaf as $y(X)$.
2. The more usual language for what it's calling "functorial in $A$ and $F$" is "natural in $A$ and $F$", because it's describing a natural transformation. The operations taking $(A,F)$ to $F(A)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(h_A,F)$ are the object parts of a pair of functors $C^{op}\times\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}\to\mathbf{Set}$, and the theorem is saying that the bijection it's displaying is a natural isomorphim. The reason you might say this explicitly is it's possible to have things that look like natural transformations, but are only actually natural if you fix one argument and treat the functors as functors only in one variable. This is just saying explicitly that this is a natural transformation that works as the $A$ argument varies, the $F$ argument varies, or both vary.
3. Here $\simeq$ means "naturally isomorphic"; it's the same statement as in the first link, just a slight difference in notation. $\mathrm{Nat}(F,G)$ is the same thing as $\mathrm{Hom}_{PreSh(C)}(F,G)$; $yA$ is the same as $h_A$.

Comment: How do you know from the first picture that $h_A$ is a functor from $\mathcal C^{op}$ to $\mathcal Set$? It's not stated anywhere. (Prior to this lemma, $h_A$ was only defined, as I pointed out, for an arbitrary category. And according to that definition, $h_A$ is a functor from $\mathcal C$, not $\mathcal C^{op}$.) Edit: probably it's implicit from the fact that they're considering the hom-set of presheafs. But again, $h_A$ was previously defined as a functor from $\mathcal C$, not from $\mathcal C^{op}$...

Comment: First of all, it follows from the definition you yourself state at the top of the post. Second, it appears in that first link in the Hom functor on the category of functors $C^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$, so it would be gibberish if it weren't in the same category as $F$.

Comment: $h_X$, as you define it above, is emphatically not a functor from $C\to\mathbf{Set}$; it is contravariant in its first argument, so either your source has a typo, or you have transcribed it wrong, or the author is not using different notations for contravariant and covariant representable functors.

Comment: @user634426 - Out of curiosity, where is the first image from?

Comment: It's from "Algebra II" by Gorodentsev. He doesn't have a typo, I indeed transcribed it wrong. It's a very extensive and rigorously written book (in two volumes), but it's almost unreadable for those who sees the material for the first time (from my point of view).

Comment: "Naturally isomorphic" means "isomorphic in a functor category". Which functor category (in this case)? And in order for $\text{Nat}(\text yf,F)$ to be naturally isomorphic to $FA$, these two things should be functors. But isn't $FA$ an object in $\mathcal {Set}$ (not a functor)? And isn't $\text{Nat}(\text yf,F)$ a class of morphisms (as opposed to being a functor)?

Comment: Naturally isomorphic in the functor category $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}\times\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}}$! Here we're describing the functors in terms of what they do on objects because writing $-(-)$ is much less clear than writing "$F(A)$." Likewise, $\mathrm{Nat}(yA,F)$ is being written to describe the functor that takes $(A,F)$ to the set $\mathrm{Nat}(yA,F)$--and I actually do say this above.

Comment: I see that you mentioned it in your answer, but I don't understand that part. What is "the object parts of a pair of functors"?  I.e., what is in general the (an?) object part of a functor? And I'm afraid I still don't understand how can $F(A)$ and $Nat(yA,F)$ be treated like functors if they are not functors. $F(A)$ has a uniquely defined meaning, and it is the image of the object $A\in Ob(C^{op})$ under the functor $F:C^{op}\to Set$. The notation $-(-):C^{op}\times Set^{C^{op}}\to Set$ at least does make sense as a functor (though I haven't verified it's a functor). Continued...

Comment: ... So as far as I can see $F(A)$ is used as a heavy abuse of notation to mean the functor $-(-):C^{op}\times Set^{C^{op}}\to Set$.

Comment: It's an entirely common abuse of notation. The way we might write $f(x,y)$ for a function of two variables, yet no one ever protests "how can that be a function, $f(x,y)$ should be a number." Get used to it, because you will see it a lot. And the "object part of a functor" is the function mapping objects of one category to the objects of another category; and there's the morphism part that maps morphisms to morphisms; combined, you have a functor.

Comment: "...no one ever protests..." Actually I do. But this analogy is helpful, thanks. However, functors have two types of inputs, so I feel it's even worse (than in the case with functions) to use such notation because then there may be 4 distinct meanings if one allows for the abuse of notation. Anyway, having accepted this abuse of notation, the only thing which still remains murky for me is naturality, but probably it's because I have no experience with natural isomorphisms. I hope this will become clear after I read and understand the proof of the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: Good luck! It can take a while to really appreciate the Yoneda lemma, but it's well worth taking time to understand if you intend to do serious category theory.